# How to bring footnotes closer to page number?

Tags: spacing, footnotes

As can be seen in the screenshot, my footnotes are abnormally far away from the page number. I use the normal `\footnote` command and have so far tried `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` and had a few ideas with the `fancyhdr` package, none of which worked. Any suggestions?

[image: Space between footnote and page number way too large]

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. And how did you define the page parameters `\bottommargin` and the placement of the page numbers?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,BCOR=0mm,bibliography=totoc,parskip=half]{thesis}

Comment: There are lots and lots of LaTeX document classes called `thesis` out there on the Internet. Which one of these might you be using? Is it available online (and, if so, where)?

Comment: Note that footnotes are placed inside the text area,  Use `\usepackage{showframe}` or `\geometry{showframe}` to see the margins being used.